# Laravel Requests never contain post data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and I'm unable to use its Request injection.

If I `print_r($request->all())`, I get an empty array:

```
Array
(
    [\] => 
)
```

But when I check `Request::getContent()`, it shows that I have content.

```
{"test": "test"}
```

Why is this? I have never had this problem before.

#### My controller method

```
public function state(Requests\CheckState $request) {
    print_r($request->all());
    print_r($request->getContent());
}
```

#### My Request

```
class CheckState extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: How are you making the request? What are you sending?

Comment: Shouldn't that rule of `token` be uncommented ?

Comment: I am using Intellij IDEA's RESTFUL tool https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/rest-client-tool-window.html and I am sending it a JSON string  `{ "test": "test" }`

Comment: @user3514160 No. It is irrelevant. I removed it from my example now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending raw JSON data to Laravel, be sure to specify `Content-Type: application/json`

This is because the [`Request`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L589) class checks for JSON content this way:

```
/**
 * Determine if the request is sending JSON.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isJson()
{
    return Str::contains($this->header('CONTENT_TYPE'), '/json');
}
```

If the header is omitted, the framework assumes the request is plaintext.